# How to simulate a long task with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am testing resolve in order to display a partial view only after receiving a response from the server (is it the good way to do that?).

To undestand better how resolve works, I would like to add a pause (5 seconds) in the service which uses $resource to get the data displayed by the partial view. In Java I would use the method sleep. Is there a simple way to wait for 5 seconds with AngularJS before executing the following lines of code (before using $resource in my service)?

Comment: Use `$timeout(function(){}, 5000)`, but this will not block! Javascript. And you shouldn't expect `$resource` to block either

Comment: Yes I had seen $timeout but, as you say, it will not delay the execution of the following lines of code and I have to create 2 functions in order to delay the use of $resource. I wonder if there exists a simple solution like in Java.

Comment: Javascript is (for the purpose of this question) is a single-threaded execution environment. If you delay the execution it will freeze the browser. You don't want that (and it also has the added benefit of not being possible, except in very rare case). You need to learn about async model - `$timeout` would help you mock it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will wait:

```
function ExampleController($scope, $timeout, $q) {

    function get() {

        var request = $q.defer();

        console.log('Waiting...');

        $timeout(function() {
            request.resolve({data:1});
        }, 5000);

        return request.promise;
    }

    get().then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
```

Basically you set up a `$q.defer()`, and then resolve it when everything that you want is loaded (or in this case when the timeout finishes). You then use the `then` function to do something with the data you resolved.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. I want to use the attribute resolve in when of $routeProvider: $routeProvider.when "/list", controller: "..", resolve: { customers: function(customerResource) return customerResource.query();}  customerResource is my service which uses $resource.

Comment: Ah apologies, I have included another answer which I think is more what you were after

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory like so:

```
function fakeResource($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        get: function() {

            var request = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function() {
                request.resolve({data:1});
            }, 5000);

            return request.promise;
        }
    }
}]);

app.factory('fakeResource', fakeResource);
```

Then in the resolve of your $routeProvider:

```
customers: function(fakeResource) {
    return fakeResource.get();
}
```